# MVC 4 IntelliSense is not working in Razor in Visual Studio 2010 not sure what is the issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

MVC 4 IntelliSense is not working in Razor in Visual Studio 2010

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by adding a new  entry with the key webPages:Version and the value 1.0.0.0. Locate the following assembly references in your project file

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages"/>  
<Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers" />
```

Replace them with the following:

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL "/> 
<Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

Save changes and reload project. For details please check the link -

https://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253815

and go through the topic - **"Installing ASP.NET MVC 4  breaks ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM applications"**

Comment: Actually, System.Web.Helpers was not available in the web.config file.
Now the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your webconfig

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <!-- New -->
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```